# foreach and index in .ToDictionary C#

Tags: c#, json, web-scraping, lambda

I am web-scraping some data and trying to write the scraped data to a json file using C# newtonsoft.Json

I get stuck when writing a foreach in my .ToDictionary function as well as not being able to ++ an index into my .ToDictionary function.

**My class:**

```
public class JsonParametersData
{
    public bool required { get; set; }
    public bool list { get; set; }
    public List<string> options { get; set; }
}
```

**My arrays**

```
var jsonData              = new List<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, JsonParametersData>>>();
var moduleParameters      = new List<string>();
var parameterOptionsArray = new List<List<string>>();
var parameterOptions      = new List<string>();
var requiredArray         = new List<bool>();
var listArray             = new List<bool>();
string moduleName         = item.Attributes["href"].Value.Replace("_module.html", "");
```

**The code which is commented shows what I am trying to do.**

```
int index = 0;
jsonData.Add(new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, JsonParametersData>>()
{
    {
        moduleName,
        moduleParameters
            .ToDictionary(n => n,
                n => new JsonParametersData
                {
                    required = requiredArray[index],
                    list = listArray[index],
                    options = new List<string>() { "option1", "option2" },
                   /*
                    foreach (var parameteroption in parameterOptionsArray[index])
                    {
                        options.Add(parameteroption);
                    }
                    index++;
                    */
                })
    }
});

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonData.ToArray());

//write string to file
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"path", json);
```

Comment: You can only make assignments within an object-initializer (that´s what the `new { ... }` is called). However you can add the options when you initialized your dictionary.

Comment: How would you do this? Can you link me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I´ve written in the comments you can make only assignments in an object-initializer. Thus the following is allowed:

```
var a = new { MyMember = anInstance }
```

whilst this is not:

```
var a = new { MyMember = anInstance, anInstance.DoSomething() };
```

That´s one of those cases where you should not use Linq at all, as it leads to more confusion than it helps. Instead use a good old-styled loop:

```
int index = 0;
var innerDict = new Dictionary<string, JsonParametersData>();

foreach(var name in moduleParameters)
{
    innerDict[name] = new JsonParametersData
                {
                    required = requiredArray[index],
                    list = listArray[index],
                    options = new List<string>() { "option1", "option2" },
                } 
    innerDict[name].Options.AddRange(parameterOptionsArray[index]);
    index++;
}

var dict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, JsonParametersData>>();
dict[moduleName] = innerDict;
jsonData.Add(dict);
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonData.ToArray());
```

Comment: How about the index? Anyway on ++ing in my JsonParametersData?

Comment: In new JsonParametersData my `requiredArray[ownIndex]` needs **its own index**. At the end, before closing the JsonParametersData, the new index needs to ++. Any simple way of doing this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ChakirBelhaj I don´t understand what you mean by "close the JsonParametersData". In your example the index should be incremented when your loop has finshed. As far as I understand this should be executed once for every `JsonParametersData`, shouldn´t it?

Comment: The code right now creates **all** JsonParametersData when the index is still 0. I want for every new JsonParametersData created, index++. This means that upon creating a new JsonParametersData the index should be incremented. I hope this explains the problem.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, even my professor couldn't help me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Your parameterOptionsArray is not an Array, but a List of lists.

The thing is that **parameterOptionsArray[index]** is a List, not a string. So you should use AddRange() instead of Add().

```
parameterOptionsArray.Foreach(parameteroption => options.AddRange(parameteroption));
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have a jagged array in `parameterOptionsArray`. You can make use of `SelectMany` here. Perhaps following sample can help:

```
    string[][] parameterOptionsArray = new string[2][];
    parameterOptionsArray[0] = new string[2];
    parameterOptionsArray[0][0] = "1";
    parameterOptionsArray[0][1] = "2";
    parameterOptionsArray[1] = new string[2];
    parameterOptionsArray[1][0] = "3";
    parameterOptionsArray[1][1] = "4";

    var testing = new {options = parameterOptionsArray.SelectMany(x => x).ToList()};        
    testing.options.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```